# How to get the statistics of tests in a plan through Bamboo API

Tags: java, rest, continuous-integration, bamboo, devops

Does anyone have an idea on how to achieve this. I have checked the API docs, but no solution.

I want to get The statistics for all the tests in a plan. Something similar to the image attached.

[image]

I use Bamboo 5.10.3

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Bamboo reports. Is there any specific reason you are looking for APIs?
You can use these APIs

```
http://myhost.com:8085/bamboo/rest/api/latest/chart [GET]
http://myhost.com:8085/bamboo/rest/api/latest/chart/reports [GET]
http://myhost.com:8085/bamboo/rest/api/latest/chart/planSummary [GET]
```